# How do you find out if theres more than one result from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement

I have a portfolio which is showing results from my database... I need to know how to find out if there's more than one of the items with the same owner using an if statement...

It's not advanced I just have a table with the company name, website address etc. and at the end a column that's named "owner" which has the owners email address...

I need to find out if there's more than one portfolio item with the same email address

Please Help

Thanks
Ben

Update: mysql_num_rows($result) is the answer

Comment: Could you post the structure of your tables?

Comment: We will need a lot more information, starting with your table structure.

Comment: This isn't enough information. Post more about the problem you're trying to solve. For example, will you be looking at each owner in turn and need to find out whether each one has more than one item? Or do you literally need to know whether there exists at least one case of a person owning more than one thing anywhere in your table?

Comment: mysql_num_rows($result) is the answer

Comment: take into account that `mysql_num_rows` counts the rows once they have been retrieved, so it may not be the most efficient way to do it... it depends on what you're doing next with that information

Answer (score 0):

So, your table looks like this:

```
portfolio
=============
company
url
owner
```

A SQL query to retrieve the number of portfolio items per owner:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Num_Portfolio_Items, owner FROM portfolio GROUP BY owner;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you should use `COUNT` in your SQL statement:

```
$email = 'some.email@address.com';
$query = mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM your_table WHERE owner = "%s"', $email));
$rs = mysql_fetch_row($query);
echo "There are " . $rs[0] . " people with " . $email . " email address.";
```